# invite user to a dropbox folder using python sdk

Tags: python-2.7, dropbox, dropbox-api

In my application I am sharing a set of images from one of my `dropbox` folder to few people and wrapping some control over it.
Since I am using `client.media('path_to_image')`, I am getting the exact `url` and putting it in html as

```
 <img src="the url returned">
```

, but with an expiry duration.

But it wont be available to other unless the image_path is available in other user's dropbox.
Though the `client.share('path_to_image')` gives a public url whose expiry date is set too ahead but, the url it returns is shortend one. So I wount be able to use that url in html img tags as src.

So the only way I could short out is to invite the users to my folder so that the image path available in there dropbox client too.

Is there a way to `invite users` to my `dropbox` folder, using dropbox python sdk or api.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, or you might be misreading the documentation for client.media().  The URL returned by that API can be used by any user without authentication (until it expires) so it's suitable for use in an  tag as you suggest.

If the short URL from client.share(path) is a problem, you can call client.share(path, short_url=False) and get an unshortened URL.  The links you get from that call don't lead directly to the image, though, but to a web page on which the image can be viewed or downloaded.  You can actually create a direct-download link (unexpiring) from a share link if you replace www.dropbox.com with dl.dropboxusercontent.com in the URL.

Comment: thanks for your response atwyman. I have read the doc again and yes I didnt noticed properly. I am able to do whatever I want to do with a url. again thanks a lot for your response